# ¿Funcionan igual removeAll y retainAll de la interfaz Collections?

Tags: java

**removeAll(Collection c)**
Borra todos los objetos de la colección que invoca que estén en c.

**retainAll(Collection c)**
En la colección que invoca sólo se quedarán aquellos objetos que están en c.(intersección)

Mi duda es , ¿funcionan de la misma manera? Puesto que retainAll tiene que eliminar los elementos no comunes , y removeAll hace la acción puesta anteriormente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `Collection#removeAll` no hay mayor misterio, elimina todos los elementos de una colección que están contenidos en la otra. Con `Collection#retainAll` es más curioso. Ambos métodos y otros de esta interface confían en los métodos `equals` y `hashCode` para la comparación. Cuando ejecutas `retainAll` comparara los elementos de ambas listas por medio de `equals`, si no lo encuentra entonces compara por referencia. Por esto es importante sobreescribir `equals` si usarás éste método.

Por ende, tiene un funcionamiento totalmente opuesto. Uno elimina elementos comunes, mientras que el otro retiene los elementos comunes.

Comment: ¿Entonces el opuesto de removeAll sería lo mismo que el retainAll?

Comment: Claro. `removeAll` remueve los elementos comunes, mientras que `retainAll` mantiene los elementos comunes. Podría decirse que son operaciones opuestas.

Comment: Muchas gracias pues , me aclaró las ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Respuesta simple: Si. Pero claro, dependerá de la clase concreta (ej. ArrayList) y de la implementación especifica.

Ambos métodos dependen del método `contains`, que depende de `indexOf`, luego `equals`, el cual depende del método `equals` del objeto contenido y por lo tanto tiene sentido que el algoritmo sea prácticamente el mismo pero con diferente condición.

[Aquí](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) tienes las fuentes de la implementación (Open JDK) de ArrayList donde puedes constatar lo que te digo. Si miras bien, veras que ambos métodos invocan a un tercer método llamado `batchRemove` que implementa el algoritmo pero cambia la condición.

Saludos.